# RegExp for catching text between parenthesis and/or quotes

Tags: java, regex

I have the strings:

```
background: url('../../footer/right.png') repeat;

background: url("../../footer/left.png") repeat;
```

And i want to extract just the URL like this:

```
../../footer/right.png

../../footer/left.png
```

My RegExps so far are

```
.*?[(\'|(\"|(|\'|\"](.*?)[\"|\'|)|\")|\')].*?

[[\\(\']([^\']*?)[\'\\)]]|[\\(\"]([^\"]*?)[\"\\)]|[\\(]([^)]*?)[\\)]|[\']([^\']*?)[\']|[\"]([^\"]*?)[\"]
```

But it keeps given me

background: url../../footer/izquierdo.png repeat;

Why it does this and what´s the correct Pattern?

**Edit**

I have come to the answer with your help, but i don´t quite know why it works

```
(?<=\\(|\'|\")(.*?)(?=\'|\"|\\))
```

Any one know why it can match any combinations of `(` `("` `('` `'` `"`     ?

And BTW, this matchs are correct for my logic (I don't mention it early but they do)

Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using something like

```
\\(('|\")(.*?)\\1\\)
```

or maybe even add `url` before

```
url\\(('|\")(.*?)\\1\\)
```

`\\1` represents match from group 1, which can be only `'` or `"`. Point in using it here is to make sure that we have same kind of quote after and before parenthesis.

This regex will place `../../footer/right.png` part in group 2, so you can just get it using `matcher.group(2)`.

---

Example:

```
String data = "background: url('../../footer/right.png') repeat;\r\n" + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "background: url(\"../../footer/left.png\") repeat;";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(('|\")(.*?)\\1\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
```

Output:

```
../../footer/right.png
../../footer/left.png
```

Comment: You have to use the `\"` in your regx :-)

Comment: @Pshemo I'm trying to use the `\\1` but it stops geting the right answer; but it's actually what now I need. Anyway, this answer gave me the idea of lookaheads, so thanks for that

Comment: `trying to use the \\1 but it stops geting the right answer` can you give example of input, expected output and output which you really are getting?

Comment: @Pshemo I was using a wrong Pattern, sorry. Already marked as the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String urlStr = "background: url('../../footer/right.png') repeat;";
String url = urlStr.split("'")[1];
System.out.println(url);
```

*output*

```
../../footer/right.png
```

Comment: I try this before, it worked but i have to make a if-else for all the combinations (     ('     ("
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use (adding escape for the quote where you need them)

```
(?|'([^']*)'|"([^"]*)")
```

Your answer will be in the first captured group (thanks to `(?|...|...)`, used to reset the capturing groups index)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
url\([\'|\"](.+)[\'|\"]\)
```

as Java string will be:

```
"url\\([\\'|\\\"](.+)[\\'|\\\"]\\)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this part of your regex:

```
[('|("|(|'|"]
```

(I've eliminated the backslashes that you need inside a Java string literal.)  When you have a set of characters enclosed by `[]` in a regex, the effect is to match *one* character that must be in the set.  Thus, `[abc]` matches one character that can either be `'a'`, `'b'`, or `'c'`.  It never matches a sequence of more than one character.  There are other features, for example using `^` as the first character means match a character *not* in the set, and there are ways to specify entire character classes such as `\d` for digit.

However, it appears that you're trying to use it to match a multiple-character sequence, i.e. you're looking for `('` or `("` in the string.  You can't use a `[]` construct for that.  The way you've written it, it will match one character that is either `(`, `'`, `|`, or `"`.